# Quote marks when concatenating string with a single character

Tags: java

What kind of quote marks should I choose for a single character when I concatenate it with a string?

```
String s1="string";
```

Should I use

```
String s2=s1+'c';
```

Or

```
String s2=s1+"c";
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use both! Give it a try!

"Why?" you ask. The magic here is the `+` operator.

When `+` is used with strings, it automatically turns the other operand into a string! That's why it can be used with `'c'`, a character literal. It can also be used with `"c"` because of course, `"c"` is a string literal.

Not only that, you can even add integers to a string:

```
String s2=s1+1;
```

Answer (score 1):

U can use it in two diferent ways : `String s2=s1+'c';` and 
`char x = 'c';
String s2 = s1 + x;`

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches are ok but if you are going into the details then perhaps

```
String s2=s1+'c';
```

will take a little less memory than the second way because char is just two bytes while String requires 8+ bytes. But I don't think that such nuances are important in most cases and also I'm not even sure that this difference will exist at all because JVM may optimize it

Answer (score 0):

Java automatically does the conversion for you, so it doesn't really matter, but I'd personally just use a string (double quotes) just because I personally prefer to minimize the 'automatic stuff' that happens if I can prevent it.

Also, if you ever decide that 'c' should be 'csomething', then you'll have to change it into a boudle quote anyway.

But I suppose I'm just nitpicking...

Answer (score 0):

Those are 2 different types of casting: *implicit casting* and *explicit casting*.

```
String s2=s1+'c';
```

This is a implicit casting, which means that the magic is done by the compiler (no overhead).

```
String s2=s1+"c";
```

This is a explicit casting, because "c" is converted to an object like:

```
Object o = "c";
String s2 = (String) o;
```

This means that the conversion must be checked for null-pointers, which will create an overhead.

Therefore, while both ways works, I prefer casting from character ('c') because that will create less overhead!

source: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076555/build-ci-sdlc/java-performance-programming--part-2--the-cost-of-casting.html